# Converting data frame columns in category type in pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, types, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame df and there I want to convert some columns into category type. Using pandas I can do it like below way:

```
    for col in categorical_collist:
        df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
```

I want to do the column conversion in pyspark. How can I do it?

I have tried using the below code in pyspark. But it is not giving my expected output during operation.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
for col in categorical_collist:
    df = df.withColumn(col, df[col].cast(StringType()))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several data types only provided by pandas, but not supported by Spark.

These kinds of pandas specific data types below are not currently supported in the pandas API on Spark but planned to be supported:

- pd.Timedelta
- pd.Categorical
- pd.CategoricalDtype

So, the answer is no, you can't data frame columns in category type in pyspark.

[Ref](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/types.html)